# Set CSS animation delay with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have some keyframe animations in my css file. There is already an animation-delay specified.
The wrapper div has the attribute data-delay.

I want to get the animation-delay in the css file and add the value of data-delay to it.
Then i want that the animation start with the new delay.

I tried `ele[i].style.animationDelay`.
But it seems that this returns null until I set a value to it.

If I set `ele[i].style.animationDelay = '5s'` the animation still runs with the delay of the css file.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper" data-delay="2s" >
    <h1 id="hi">Hi</h1>
    <h1 id="name">test!</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { font-size: 300%; }

#wrapper h1 { position: absolute; }

#hi {
    transform: translate(-200px, 100px);

    animation-name: hi;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

#name {
    transform: translate(-200px, 150px);

    animation-name: name;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes hi{
    100% { transform: translate(50px, 100px) };
}

@keyframes name{
    100% { transform: translate(50px, 150px) };
}
```

JS

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var ele = wrapper.children;
var delay = wrapper.getAttribute('data-delay');

for (var i=0;i<ele.length;i++) {

    alert(ele[i].style.animationDelay);
    ele[i].style.animationDelay = delay;
    alert(ele[i].style.animationDelay);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FHuKN/4/

Comment: You'll need to prefix all those. :/ (`-moz-animation-name`, `.style.mozAnimationDelay`, etc)

Comment: It works for me with prefixes: http://jsfiddle.net/FHuKN/5/. But note that the camel case version of a prefixed property starts with a capital letter.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FHuKN/6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've only tested this on Mac 10.8 Chrome 25, Safari 6.0, and FF 18.0.

Sounds like the main thing you wanted to do was add the `data-delay` value to whatever existing animation delay was applied to the elements.

HTML - unchanged

```
<div id="wrapper" data-delay="5.1s" >
    <h1 id="hi">Hi</h1>
    <h1 id="name">test!</h1>
</div>
```

CSS - Vendor prefixes and initial keyframes (0%) were added.

```
body { font-size: 300%; }

#wrapper h1 { position: absolute; }

#hi { 
    -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, 100px);
    -webkit-animation-name: hi;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.1s;

    -moz-transform: translate(-200px, 100px);
    -moz-animation-name: hi;
    -moz-animation-duration: .5s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2.1s;

    transform: translate(-200px, 100px);
    animation-name: hi;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 2.1s;
}

#name { 
    -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, 150px);
    -webkit-animation-name: name;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3.1s;

    -moz-transform: translate(-200px, 150px);
    -moz-animation-name: name;
    -moz-animation-duration: .5s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3.1s;

    transform: translate(-200px, 150px);
    animation-name: name;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 3.1s;
}

@-moz-keyframes hi{
    0% { -moz-transform: translate(-200px, 100px); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translate(50px, 100px); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hi {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, 100px); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 100px); }
}
@keyframes hi{
    0% { transform: translate(-200px, 100px); }
    100% { transform: translate(50px, 100px); }
}

@-moz-keyframes name {
    0% { -moz-transform: translate(-200px, 150px); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translate(50px, 150px); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes name {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, 150px); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 150px); }
}
@keyframes name {
    0% { transform: translate(-200px, 150px); }
    100% { transform: translate(50px, 150px); }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

On an element, the `style` property doesn't hold all the style information because it only represents what is being set directly on the element via the `style` attribute. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.style#Notes)

[window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) seems to work pretty well.

Juggling the prefixed properties is a little clunky, but it worked in the browsers I tested with.

```
(function(undefined) {

    var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper'),
        elms = wrapper.children,
        delay = wrapper.getAttribute('data-delay'),
        prop,
        styl,
        cur,
        i;

    delay = !delay ? 0 : Number(delay.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));

    if (!elms.length) {
        return;
    }

    styl = window.getComputedStyle(elms[0]);

    if (styl.getPropertyValue('animation-delay')) {
        prop = 'animation-delay';

    } else if (styl.getPropertyValue('-webkit-animation-delay')) {
        prop = '-webkit-animation-delay';

    } else if (styl.getPropertyValue('-moz-animation-delay')) {
        prop = '-moz-animation-delay';

    } else {
        console.log('unable to find prop');
        return;
    }
    // console.log('prop', prop);

    for (i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
        styl = window.getComputedStyle(elms[i]);
        cur = styl.getPropertyValue(prop);
        cur = Number(cur.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
        elms[i].style.setProperty(prop, (cur + delay) + 's');

        console.log('delay: ' + cur + 's -> ' + (cur + delay) + 's')
    }

})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FHuKN/11/

Comment: Tested it today in Firefox. Can somebody explain me why I have to write `elms[i].style['animationDelay]` instead of `animation-delay` to get it working? And why plays Chrome the animation after cur+dur secs and Firefox directly after cur secs without the delay?

Comment: @tryzor I see what you mean. I've been looking at it and it's driving me nuts. Thanks for pointing it out...

Answer (score 0):

Old Firefoxes (at least up to 16), Opera before migrating to Blink (<15), IE at least 10 - will not redraw the animation if we just change some of its attributes like `(-prefix-)animation-delay`. In order to make them do so, we have to apply some depper tricks.

1. The first will be **removing and reinserting the animated element**. And - for the sake of Webkit - applying all the style changes on it.

Just change the code from @tiffon's fiddle

```
elms[i].style.setProperty(prop, (cur + delay) + 's');
```

To

```
var newEl =  elms[i].cloneNode(true);
newEl.style.setProperty(prop, (cur + delay) + 's', '');
elms[i].parentNode.replaceChild(newEl,elms[i]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FHuKN/28/

1. Remove the class name ar the attribute value, which the animation is attached to, wait for a bit (`setTimeout`) of - better - trigger the reflow (say, `element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;`), and add the class name again.

http://jsfiddle.net/FHuKN/29/

The idea is not mine, all credit goes to [Chris Coyer](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)